# How to split in string with comma, backslash, and keep the comma and backslash at their position in python

Tags: python-3.x, split

I have string like this

```
My address 47/8,New Jersey, USA
```

I want to split like this

```
['My','address', '47/', '8,', 'New Jersey', 'USA']
```

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy way to split the string in this fashion.

You could use `{list_var} = {string_var}.split(" ")` or use `{list_var} = {string_var}.split(",")` but it won't be exactly how you want it.

You could use something that measures the length of the list after doing the operations above on them and decide how you want to behave with the list after using the length to determine what variables would be in given positions within the list.